# WP function get_error_message() returns message always in English

Tags: php, wordpress

I use qTranslate-X and  a custom login form for users. If user login or password is incorrect I have called `get_error_message()` for message displaying. It all times return English string.

I have tried `define ('WPLANG', 'ru_RU')`, but still not working

Comment: Please make sure you have configured correctly

Comment: my code: `if (is_wp_error($user)) {return $user->get_error_message()};`

Answer (score 0):

define ('WPLANG', '')  is deprecated since version 4.0
[Changeset 29630][1] 
It has been moved to database.

If you are sure your configuration is correct try

```
$locale='ru_RU';
```

in wp-config.php file